# Laravel - Displaying products based on categories but not able to display category name in blade file

Tags: php, laravel

Help needed in laravel

I am trying to display products based on category & i have done that. I need to display the category name in product view file but not able to.

Created table

products with id , pname , cid

categories with id , cname

Route file : Route::get('/categories/{id}', 'CategoriesController@show');
Route::get('/categories/', 'CategoriesController@index');

> My Controller

```
public function show($id)
    {

    $category_products=product::where('cid',$id)->get();

    return view ('product',compact('category_products',$id));

    }
```

> My View

```
@foreach ($category_products as $product)

{{$product->$product->pname}}

@foreach
```

I want to display the category name above the products list

Comment: First thing I would suggest using eager loading. Please, have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading Could you show your table of `product` and `category`. Also, if it is named correctly, it should be $product->category->category_name (you might have different naming but you need to  call category relationship from product)

Comment: Do you have the relationship set in your Model?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert in category model public function Product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }  in product model public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(category::class);
    }

Comment: @Mohamed Please check the answer - if it solves your question please don't forget to accept it 

Answer (score 7):

In your Category Model add the relationship:

```
public function products(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Product','cid');
}
```

In your Controller, get all categories and eager load your Products:

```
$categories=Category::with('products')->get();
return view ('product',compact('categories'));
```

In your blade view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{$category->cname}}
    @foreach ($category->products as $product)
        {{$product->pname}}
    @foreach
@foreach
```

Comment: Thank you. Guys like you who leave answers to questions make Stack Overflow a better place. "smiley emoji".